# Is possible to improve html2canvas screenshot?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am trying to get a screenshot of a complicated webpage. Only reasonable solution I managed to found is html2canvas, but it does not render the page completely ok.

This is real screenshot:
[image]
And this is html2canvas output:
[image]

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  allowTaint: true,
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  scrollX: window.pageXOffset,
  scrollY: window.pageYOffset,
  x: window.pageXOffset,
  y: window.pageYOffset
}).then(function(canvas) {
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.write('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
});
```

I am using version 0.5. This source code was taken directly from the the html2canvas main page.

Is it possible to somehow improve it, or is there any better alternative? I really don't care about the plots, the left part of the page concerns me.

P.S. The use case is to add a button to our web application, which would allow users to report a bug with attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1**

Use timeout for applying color and take image.Time provide to then function inside.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  allowTaint: true,
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  scrollX: window.pageXOffset,
  scrollY: window.pageYOffset,
  x: window.pageXOffset,
  y: window.pageYOffset
}).then(function(canvas) { // timeout function
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.write('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
});
```

**Step:2**

Yes, I am having solutions. You may use phantom headless browser or chrome headless browser.

In your case, Charts color not applying for charting data and color plotting reason in html2canvas plugin.

Phantom js you may header&footer and all customization.